# Convert String to JSON and prettify it in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am receiving the following data from server:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f42eb030ce39b30b86a6519"), "username" : "test", "password" : "$2a$10$95H4m8QFoeeA0bF4klEb2OIQ8/SIz0raOJG" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f42efa1b9f7e2321c55a9c1"), "username" : "admin", "password" : "$2a$10$G/gGYVVxO/RDuoDXIS0iSeFsKAOw9Cs8HlCa3U" }
```

I want to convert it to valid JSON object and prettify it for viewing. Some methods I tried:

```
let data = ({ "_id" : ObjectId("5f42eb030ce39b30b86a6519"), "username" : "test", "password" : "$2a$10$95H4m8QFoeeA0bF4klEb2OIQ8/SIz0raOJG" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f42efa1b9f7e2321c55a9c1"), "username" : "admin", "password" : "$2a$10$G/gGYVVxO/RDuoDXIS0iSeFsKAOw9Cs8HlCa3U" })
```

**1.** `data = data.trim().replace("} {", "}, {")` //to put a comma (,) between tow {}.

**2.**  `data = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);` //It generates "backslash(\)" after every word

**3.** `data=JSON.parse(data)` //It converts to String JSON but I want Object JSON.

After doing `JSON.stringify((JSON.parse(data)), null, 4);` this is the response I am getting:

```
 ["{ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"5f42eb030ce39b30b86a6519\"), \"username\" : \"test\", \"password\" : \"$2a$10$95H4m8QFoeeA0bF4klEb2OIQ8/SIz0raOJG\" }, 
{ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"5f42efa1b9f7e2321c55a9c1\"), \"username\" : \"admin\", \"password\" : \"$2a$10$G/gGYVVxO/RDuoDXIS0iSeFsKAOw9Cs8HlCa3U\" }"]
```

How can I convert it to valid JSON object and prettify it for viewing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "String JSON" instead of "Object JSON". `JSON.parse()` should work.

Comment: I am getting this after doing JSON.parse(): 
[
  '{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f42eb030ce39b30b86a6519"), "username" : "test", "password" : "$2a$10$95H4m8QFoeeA0bF4klEb2OIQ8/SIz0raOJG" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("5f42efa1b9f7e2321c55a9c1"), "username" : "admin", "password" : "$2a$10$G/gGYVVxO/RDuoDXIS0iSeFsKAOw9Cs8HlCa3U" }'
] 

But when I use JSON.stringify(data, null, 4); to prettify I am getting loads of slash(\\) like this:

["{ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"5f42eb030ce39b30b86a6519\"), \"username\" : \"test\", .......and so on"]

Comment: It is not a valid JSON string. Open your web browsers. Open the debug console. Do "let a = '...your string...' then JSON.parse(a). It will fail because there are invalid characters at ObjectId.

Comment: Understood, so how can I make it valid?

Comment: [JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use regex to escape the double quotes inside de `ObjectId`, and then fix the `ObjectId`. First insert a comma `,` between objects, the idea on your first list item was correct but maybe the separator was not a `single` space, or maybe was a `line break`, so it's better to use th regex `/}\s*{/`.

```js
const resp = `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f42eb030ce39b30b86a6519"), "username" : "test",
 "password" : "$2a$10$95H4m8QFoeeA0bF4klEb2OIQ8/SIz0raOJG" }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5f42efa1b9f7e2321c55a9c1"), "username" : "admin", "password" :
 "$2a$10$G/gGYVVxO/RDuoDXIS0iSeFsKAOw9Cs8HlCa3U" }`;

fixMultObj = resp.replace(/}\s*{/, '}, {');
console.log(fixMultObj)
/*
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f42eb030ce39b30b86a6519"), "username" : "test", "password" :
 "$2a$10$95H4m8QFoeeA0bF4klEb2OIQ8/SIz0raOJG" }, { "_id" :
ObjectId("5f42efa1b9f7e2321c55a9c1"), "username" : "admin", "password" :
 "$2a$10$G/gGYVVxO/RDuoDXIS0iSeFsKAOw9Cs8HlCa3U" }
*/
```

Now you can escape the double quotes surrounding the ObjectId hex value, and add the double quotes on the ObjectId itself.

```js
fixQuotes = fixMultObj.replace(/ObjectId\("(\S+)"\)/g, '"ObjectId(\\"$1\\")"');
console.log(fixQuotes)
/*
{ "_id" : "ObjectId(\"5f42eb030ce39b30b86a6519\")", "username" : "test", "password" :
 "$2a$10$95H4m8QFoeeA0bF4klEb2OIQ8/SIz0raOJG" }, { "_id" :
"ObjectId(\"5f42efa1b9f7e2321c55a9c1\")", "username" : "admin","password" :
"$2a$10$G/gGYVVxO/RDuoDXIS0iSeFsKAOw9Cs8HlCa3U" }
*/
```

Make the array notation to be able to reach multiple objects.

```js
makeArray = JSON.parse(`[${fixQuotes}]`)

console.log(makeArray)
/*
[ { _id: 'ObjectId("5f42eb030ce39b30b86a6519")',
    username: 'test',
    password: '$2a$10$95H4m8QFoeeA0bF4klEb2OIQ8/SIz0raOJG' },
  { _id: 'ObjectId("5f42efa1b9f7e2321c55a9c1")',
    username: 'admin',
    password: '$2a$10$G/gGYVVxO/RDuoDXIS0iSeFsKAOw9Cs8HlCa3U' } ]
*/
```

And get the desired values from the JSON object.

```js
console.log(makeArray[1]._id)
// ObjectId("5f42efa1b9f7e2321c55a9c1")
```